# How get Date format in notifications collection

Tags: laravel

I need to define the date format for a collection. I tried it that way, but it doesn't work:

```
return response()->json($request->user()->notifications()->format('d/m/Y')->limit(7)->get());
```

How could I set the date format for an entire collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reckon you are using [database notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#database-notifications) and you want to format the `created_at` field.

To return the results fast, you might do something like this:

```php
$notifications = $user->notifications()
    ->limit(7)
    ->get()
    ->each(function ($notification) {
        $notification->formatted_created_at = $notification->created_at->format('d/m/Y');
    });
```

I suggest that you do it properly and create a new [API resource](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#introduction).

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class NotificationResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the notification into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            // ...
            'formatted_created_at' => $this->created_at->format('d/m/Y'),
        ];
    }
}

// In the controller action
$notifications = $user->notifications()
    ->limit(7)
    ->get();

return NotificationResource::collection($notifications);
```

Comment: Thaaanks :))))) (Y)